# What is an efficient way to use groupby & apply a custom function for a huge dataset and avoid shuffling?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, dask

I am trying to use `groupby` and `apply` a custom function on a huge dataset, which is giving me memory errors and the workers are getting killed because of the shuffling. How can I avoid shuffle and do this efficiently.

I am reading around fifty 700MB (each) parquet files and the data in those files is isolated, i.e. no group exists in more than one file. If I try running my code on one file, it works fine but fails when I try to run on the complete dataset.

Dask documentation talks about problems with `groupby` when you apply a custom function on groups, but they do not offer a solution for such data:
http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-groupby.html#difficult-cases

How can I process my dataset in a reasonable timeframe (it takes around 6 minutes for groupby-apply on a single file) and hopefully avoid shuffle. I do not need my results to be sorted, or `groupby` trying to sort my complete dataset from different files.

I have tried using `persist` but the data does not fit into RAM (32GB). Even though dask does not support multi column index, but I tried adding a index on one column to support groupby to no avail. Below is what the structure of code looks like:

```
from dask.dataframe import read_parquet

df = read_parquet('s3://s3_directory_path')
results = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).apply(custom_function).compute()

# custom function sorts the data within a group (the groups are small, less than 50 entries) on a field and computes some values based on heuristics (it computes 4 values, but I am showing 1 in example below and other 3 calculations are similar)

def custom_function(group):
    results = {}
    sorted_group = group.sort_values(['C']).reset_index(drop=True)
    sorted_group['delta'] = sorted_group['D'].diff()
    sorted_group.delta = sorted_group.delta.shift(-1)
    results['res1'] = (sorted_group[sorted_group.delta < -100]['D'].sum() - sorted_group.iloc[0]['D'])
    # similarly 3 more results are generated
    results_df = pd.DataFrame(results, index=[0])
    return results_df
```

One possibility is that I process one file at a time and do it multiple times, but in that case dask seems useless (no parallel processing) and it will take hours to achieve the desired results. Is there any way to do this efficiently using dask, or any other library? How do people deal with such data?

Comment: After a very quick perusal of your linked reference, it would seem the data errors and running out of memory was due to not enough shuffling, given the size of your overall data set, rather than too much.  Is there some way you can do a less than everything but more than one at a time approach?  I don't know how much overhead stuff has in this processing, but I could imagine you maybe being able to run 10-20 jobs in parallel, just not 50.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. My memory consumption was > 20GB (on a 32 GB machine) already for 1 file. May be I can fit one more and do 2 at a time, but I doubt if it can be more. The warnings are probably because dask is trying to shuffle data to be able to sort it and generate groups from it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid shuffling and can promise that groups are well isolated, then you could just call a pandas groupby apply across every partition with map_partitions

```
df.map_partitions(lambda part: part.groupby(...).apply(...))
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning this in the docs! Also, I think the `processes` scheduler works best in this case.

Comment: I am new to Dask. What does it mean by "groups are well isolated"? My understanding is that In an individual partition of a dask dataframe, it is not guaranteed to have a unique value of your groupby column.

Comment: Also, in your answer, if multiple partitions share a common value of the groupby column. will the custom function be applied multiple times on the value of the groupby column and each time a subset is applied?

Comment: I believe groups are well isolated means "no overlap of values on group by column" across partitions. No, I have tested custom function doesn't get applied multiple times.